# What is the impact of deleting and recreating a windows account on team foundation server?

Tags: active-directory, team-foundation-server

If I delete and re-create a windows account with the same name and permissions, what would be the impact on team foundation server?

Comment: Dunno, have you created a test account and tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None. What did you expect to happen?